# XNA 4.0 equivalent of RenderTarget2D.GetTexture()?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I'm currently working on a game and I'm trying to implement a color key collision. I followed [the road not taken tutorial](http://www.xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/theroadnottaken/theroadnottaken.shtml), and worked until the point of getting the texture from the render target, which is unavailable in XNA 4 and I don't seem to find an equivalent? Any help :D

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In XNA 4.0 the RenderTarget2D class inherits from Texture2D, which means that you can simply cast your render target to a texture:

```
Texture2D texture = (Texture2D)renderTarget;
```

Comment: Correct. But some important clarification: You don't even have to cast it explicitly. `RenderTarget2D` *is* a `Texture2D`, so you can can just use it anywhere you would use a `Texture2D`. What is *especially* important to point out - because I've seen a lot of people get tripped up by the code you posted - is that **at no point is a copy being made here**. In this case: `texture` still refers to the *same* object as `renderTarget`.

Comment: Thanks guys ! Really helpful ! Sorry for my late reply.